# mDP kay agreement protocol where z's are found on the step where the common key is generated?

Tags: keys, key-exchange

Whilst I was studying the mDP protocol I came across into the following step:

> **Group Key agreement:**
>   Each $U_i$ checks whether $z_1 \bigoplus ... \bigoplus z_n = 0$ and whether all signatures $\sigma_i$ are valid and aborts if any of these checks fails. Otherwise, $U_i$ proceeds as follows:
>   iteratively for each $j=i,...i+n-1: z'_{j,j+1}:=z'_{j-1,j} \bigoplus z_j $
>   ...

But I cannot understand on the notation what does it mean by $z'_{j-1,j}$ where does it find it is the $z_i$ received from the other participants?

The paper is in [springler](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-12678-9_21) and is titled as;

"Flexible Group Key Exchange with On-Demand Computation of Subgroup Keys (Full Version)" authored by: Abdalla Michel, Chevalier Celine,Manulis Mark,Pointcheval David

an alternative from [Pointcheval's](https://www.di.ens.fr/david.pointcheval/Documents/Papers/2010_africacryptB.pdf) web site.

Comment: could you post a link to the article?

Comment: Info added, keep in mind that the paper is free only via academic vpn but there are many other.

Comment: Everything is clear now?

Comment: An another question arose The participant got the $z_i$ from others, ans all $z_i$ Xore'd equals , then where the  $z'_j-1,j$ is located at the first time the participant calculates the common key. I would love an execution example (or a link to interactive simulator)

Comment: Well, I looked at it for fun, when I've found the time. If you look at the $z_i$ calculation, you will see that, if everybody is semi-honest, the $\oplus =0$. The $z'_{j-1,j}$ are stored on the users when calculated. I believe you can program this very easily.

Comment: So the $z'_j-1,j$ is the calculation of $z'_j-1,j=H(k'_{i-1,i} , sid_i)$ right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in page 6, **Each** $U_i$ proceeds as follows;

- compute $\text{sid}_i:= U_1|y_1,\ldots,U_n|y_n)$,
- $z'_{i-1,i} := H(k'_{i-1,i}, \text{sid}_i)$,
- $z'_{i+1,i} := H(k'_{i+1,i}, \text{sid}_i)$,
- $z_i := z'_{i-1,i} \oplus z'_{i+1,i}$,
- $\sigma_i := \text{Sign}(sk_i, (U_i,z_i,\text{sid}_i ))$,
- $\text{broadcast} (U_i,z_i,\sigma_i)$.

since in the beginning, the $(U_i,y_i)$ is broadcasted the above calculation is fine.

When a user $U_j$ gets all $(U_i,z_i,\sigma_i) , 1 \leq i \leq n$, he is ready to verify. Actually, they agree on a key with their neighbors by Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange protocol.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I started looking back for this a while ago. Nice to hear the same idea. And it is encouraging them to ask questions and sometimes they can be very interesting. This comment will not auto-destruct :P